# How can i read a csv based on data in other columns?

Tags: python, csv

Heres my example csv:

```
col1:  col2:  col3:
1      true   false
2      true   true
3      false  false
4      false  true
5      true   true
```

i want to be able to say 'give me col1 if col2 is true and col3 is false' 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have any code from something you've tried so far?

Comment: @esqew ive been learning SQL syntax i thought i could use a FROM clause however im not 100% sure it will work - but no example code for this

Comment: Why would you run SQL directly on a CSV? You want to be looking into `Pandas` library really but there is also the `csv` module in the standard library if you don't want the dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the built-in [`csv` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to iterate over each row's values will do the trick:

```
import csv
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    csvin = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in csvin:
        if row['col2:'] == "true" and row['col3:'] == "false":
            print(row['col1:'])
```

Output result:

> 1

Answer (score 0):

if the file can be opened in Excel I would use xlwings, which is available via `pip install xlwings`. The code would be something like `if sheet.range('B{}'.format(row)).value == 'true' and sheet.range('C{}'.format(row)).value == 'false': print(sheet.range('A{}'.format(row)).value`

Comment: after loading the book in and then loading in the sheet as well

Comment: okay cheers will try this, any idea why i got all the down votes...i thought it was a decent question

Comment: There is no need to open a CSV file in an Excel library. There is a `csv` module in the standard library (no dependencies) that is designed for the file type...

Comment: Probably because you didn't post any attempt at coding it yourself. People on here don't like answering questions that seem like "Please do this for me". I figure I won't do it for the poster, but might as well point them in the direction I would take, but that's just me

Comment: Because I've voted to close. I'm not sure that there needs to be another CSV answer on SO on something like this. I have, however, pointed both of you to the relevant library